# SQL convert to week day and hh:mm

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime

Not sure can we convert datetime field column, for example:

```
Contactdate
2020-03-12 16:20:34.000
2020-01-01 00:52:34.000
```

become

```
contact date
Wednesday 12:52
Thursday  04:20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use [`format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for this:

```
select format(contactdate, N'dddd hh\:mm') formated_date
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4827cdfcb448d682abf8edc2c0863de6)**:

```
select contactdate, format(contactdate, N'dddd hh\:mm') formated_date
from (values 
    (cast('2020-03-12 16:20:34.000' as datetime)), 
    (cast('2020-01-01 00:52:34.000' as datetime))
) as t(contactdate)
```

```
contactdate             | formated_date  
:---------------------- | :--------------
2020-03-12 16:20:34.000 | Thursday 04:20 
2020-01-01 00:52:34.000 | Wednesday 12:52
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @d table(Contactdate datetime);

INSERT @d VALUES('2020-03-12 16:20:34.000'),('2020-01-01 00:52:34.000');

SELECT contact = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Contactdate), 
       date    = CONVERT(CHAR(5), Contactdate, 108)
FROM @d;
```

I tend to stay away from `FORMAT()` - while convenient and flexible, [it does not scale in my testing](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but).